# Boxplot Issue: Non numeric argument for Binary Operator

Tags: r, boxplot

Alright so I am trying to make a boxplot. For starters this is what a part of my data looks like:

```
 Treatment   Samplename   Cp_ rp49   Cp_ RpL13a    Cp_ Att  2   
Control T0    T0: C1.1  22.37439066 19.71617973 26.79406584 3   
Control T1    T1: C1.1  27.70984514  21.6094783 31.37710115 4   
Control T0     T0: C1.2 23.94895554  20.2301651 28.07790884 5   
Control T1     T1: C1.2  24.9460447 20.65787086   31.059088 6   
Control T0    T0: C1.3  20.65417772 19.45722779 27.99254728 7   
Control T1    T1: C1.3  23.35409393 22.00902552 32.88400615 8   
Control T0    T0: C1.4  20.90256385 20.06997278 28.50471711 9   
Control T1    T1: C1.4  21.72104997 20.16717242 30.77175249 10  
Control T0    T0: C1.5  20.02601658 18.97854848 29.33999551 11  
Control T1    T1: C1.5  22.53037788 21.09500453 29.54695224 12  
Matched T0    T0: M1.1  20.82294039 20.07027204 28.42884012 13  
Matched T1    T1: M1.1  23.09561604 21.73694742 31.61233879
```

Now I want to make a boxplot that from the first and the fourth column by using

```
library(boxplotdbl)
boxplot(Cp_ATT~Treatment, data=df)
```

and I am running into the error "non numeric argument for binary operator"
Is there any way i can make this work without changing the names of the first column to numbers?
I hope I have stated this question correctly, thank you very much in advance.

Edit*

```
str(df)

    data.frame':    30 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ Treatment        : chr  "Control T0" "Control T1" "Control T0" "Control T1" ...
 $ Samplename       : chr  "T0: C1.1 " "T1: C1.1 " "T0: C1.2" "T1: C1.2" ...
 $ Cp_ rp49         : chr  "22.37439066" "27.70984514" "23.94895554" "24.9460447" ...
 $ Cp_ RpL13a       : chr  "19.71617973" "21.6094783" "20.2301651" "20.65787086" ...
 $ Cp_ Att          : chr  "26.79406584" "31.37710115" "28.07790884" "31.059088" ...
 $ Wichtig          : chr  "-4.419675173" "-3.667256008" "-4.1289533" "-6.113043298" ...
 $ dif_ RpL13aAtt1  : chr  "-7.077886105" "-9.767622856" "-7.847743741" "-10.40121714" ...
 $ Cp_ Def 2        : chr  "25.91183294" "30.75748354" "30.34625461" "30.49043802" ...
 $ dif_ rp49Def 2   : chr  "-3.537442276" "-3.047638397" "-6.397299069" "-5.544393316" ...
 $ dif_ RpL13aDef 2 : chr  "-6.195653208" "-9.148005245" "-10.11608951" "-9.832567163" ...
 $ Cp_ Def 3        : chr  "27.17909334" "34.26648509" "30.87750323" "34.67511797" ...
 $ dif_ rp49Def 3   : chr  "-4.804702672" "-6.556639948" "-6.92854769" "-9.729073266" ...
 $ dif_RpL13aDef 3  : chr  "-7.462913604" "-12.6570068" "-10.64733813" "-14.01724711" ...
 $ Cp_ Thau         : chr  "27.08349884" "32.82539626" "31.04172596" "30.54862188" ...
 $ dif_ rp49Thau    : chr  "-4.709108175" "-5.115551113" "-7.092770414" "-5.602577177" ...
 $ dif_ RpL13aThau  : chr  "-7.367319108" "-11.21591796" "-10.81156086" "-9.890751023" ...
```

Comment: `str(df)` might help identify what the problem is

Comment: df$Cp_ATT is a character.. did you read in the table wrongly? It should be a numeric column i guess

Comment: ```df$Cp_ATT = as.numeric(df$Cp_ATT) ; boxplot(Cp_ATT~Treatment, data=df)  ``` might solve the issue, but I would check why the table is read in wrongly, or why the data.frame is such

Comment: I agree with @StupidWolf... check your data to see why the columns are being imported as character vectors.